# How to pass 2D map as a parameter to a function in c++?

Tags: c++, function, stdmap

I have a map like

```
std::map< int, int> random[50];
```

How can i pass this map as a parameter to a function say Perform()?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is perform() an existing function or you are going to write one?

Comment: That's not a map, that's an array of 50 maps. Is this definitely what you mean by '2D map'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Perform( std::map< int, int > r[], size_t numElements );
```

or

```
void Perform( std::map< int, int >* r, size_t numElements );
```

Then, either way, call

```
Perform( random, 50 );
```

Edit:  this can also be called as follows for any const array size.

```
Perform( random, sizeof( random ) / sizeof ( random[0] ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that Perform() has some way of knowing the size of random, you could pass a pointer to random... eg:

Perform(&random);

Alternatively, you could use a std::list of std::maps, and pass a pointer (or even a copy) of that list to Perform():

Perform(random); or Perform(&random);

depending on how Perform is declared, of course.

Comment: You could also pass a reference to that std::list of std::map's.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I was going for with the Perform(&random)

Comment: Correct - my bad! I guess that means it's time for bed. Well spotted, and sorry if I caused any confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you can make `Perform` a template function or not, you can choose to

- pass the map by (const) reference: `void Perform( const std::map<int,int> (& map)[50] )`
- pass a pointer and a size (the C way)
- create a template that automatically deduces the size of the array

This is a code fragment illustrating all three of them.

```
#include <map>

// number 50 hard coded: bad practice!
void Perform( const std::map<int,int> (& maps ) [50]  ) {}

// C-style array passing: pointer and size
void Perform( const std::map<int,int>* p_maps, size_t numberofmaps ){}

// 'modern' C++: deduce the map size from the argument.
template<size_t N>
void TPerform( const std::map<int,int> (& maps)[N] ) {}



int main() {
    std::map<int,int> m [ 50 ];
    Perform( m );
    Perform( m, 50 );
    TPerform( m );
}
```

Comment: I left out the version where the array is passed in by value, assuming that this would cost unnecessary performance.

Comment: Looks like you included that as the second option "c-style array passing". I dunno of another way to actually copy it when passing. :)

Comment: I meant real value-passing, like `Perform( map<int,int> arg[50] )`.  Although this may be translated as pointer-passing, indeed.